# SMTP Client implementation

Tags: networking, smtp, email-client, duplicate

I'm implementing SMTP client. 
What should the client do once it already sent the "." at the end of the mail, but didn't receive "250 Ok"?

This is how the conversation between the client and server look like:

```
Server Response: 220 www.sample.com ESMTP Postfix
Client Sending : HELO domain.com
Server Response: 250 Hello domain.com
Client Sending : MAIL FROM: <me@domain.com>
Server Response: 250 Ok
Client Sending : RCPT TO: <friend@sample.com>
Server Response: 250 Ok
Client Sending : DATA
Server Response: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Client Sending : Subject: Example Message
Client Sending : From: me@domain.com
Client Sending : To: you@sample.com
Client Sending :
Client Sending : TEST MAIL
Client Sending : 
Client Sending : .
Server Response: 250 Ok: queued as 23411
Client Sending : QUIT
```

I'm not sure what should I do if the client sends "." and doesn't receive the 250 Ok - because of possible network error.
Was the "." sent or not? Should the client resend the mail - and - maybe - duplicate the item, or not - and risk in losing an important mail item?

Thank you.

Comment: Good question, I would like to hear an answer for this too!

Comment: Are you building this as part of a server or on the client programmer side?

Comment: @random
Hi. I have modified the question and tried to make it clearer.
This is a client side program. It is stated in the question "SMTP Client" in the first line.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) says, “Until the sender has received that 250 reply [the server’s positive reply to the end-of-data], it must assume the message was not delivered.” and “A message can be doubled if there is a communication failure at this time, …”

Comment: The only proper answer is "Read the specifications for the SMTP protocol" (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt).  Yes it is dull and boring but that's the only place you'll find the right answers.

Comment: Why is this question on hold? @random Please unlock.

Comment: @random - I don't understand what is not clear.
The specific problem: Was the "." sent or not? Should the client resend the mail - and - maybe - duplicate the item, or not - and risk in losing an important mail item?
Please reopen the question.